# Flutter IOS app stuck at Launch Screen while run

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I have been battling with an issue for weeks now and its getting frustrating. My flutter android apk builds and runs well on android but I also tried running on iOS emulator but it has been stuck on the launch screen and doesn't go further.

**Things I have tried.**

1) Added these files to script under build phases in Xcode.

```
"$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
"$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin
```

2) Added `FirebaseApp.configure()` to my `AppDelegate` file.

3) Reinstalled flutter

4) Switched to various flutter channels

**This is the error from Xcode:**

```
2020-04-24 15:02:34.421613+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243353] Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
2020-04-24 15:02:34.774843+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243704] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:62748/_bDwywAMqhg=/
2020-04-24 15:02:34.943017+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243695] [VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(127)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
2020-04-24 15:02:34.943706+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243695] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(437)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
2020-04-24 15:02:35.027558+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243628] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2020-04-24 15:02:35.083060+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243625] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-04-24 15:02:35.084616+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243625] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60300000 started
2020-04-24 15:02:35.085987+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243625] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2020-04-24 15:02:35.884479+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243728] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-24 15:02:36.240827+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243628] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800003] Registered an SDK that has already registered. Default flags will be overwritten. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-24 15:02:36.274854+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243628] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-24 15:02:36.686320+0100 Kashbase[23884:5243628] 6.18.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend in such case is to:

1. Switch to the desired Flutter channel (e.g. beta)
2. Clean the project with `flutter clean`
3. Remove ios directory (make sure to have backup or git history before deleting)
4. Recreate the ios project with: `flutter create .` run inside the project directory. This should create fresh iOS project
5. Call `flutter pub get`

You can also try to update the iOS pods by:

1. Updating the pods repository by running in ios dir: `pod repo update`
2. Reinstalling pods by: `pod install`